# Replace all strings which do not include at least one letter

Tags: r, regex

I want to delete strings which contains only special characters. If there is at least one letter or number the string should be left as is.

```r
test_cases <- c("a", "&", "&& ", "& &", "& ", "&a", "& a", "1", "& 1", "&1", "& a d", "a ")
exp_out <- c("a", "", "", "", "", "&a", "& a", "1", "& 1", "&1", "& a d", "a ")
```

I used a negative look ahead for that:

```r
gsub("^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+(?! *[a-zA-Z0-9]+ *)", "", test_cases, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "a"     ""      ""      ""      ""      "&a"    "& a"   "1"     "& 1"   "&1"    "& a d" "a "
```

This `regex` seems to be rather verbose and while testing I had to adapt it several times, because I forgot some edge cases. Thus, I was wondering whether I can come up with a "simpler" regex, that is a `regex` which is shorter?

Comment: As a start, many regex flavours support the \w metacharacter that is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] - although I do not know whether r supports this metacharacter.

Comment: @TonyR R uses several regex libraries. `perl = TRUE` means PCRE is used. `\w` will be used as a PCRE `\w`, so, it will work as you described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
test_cases[!grepl("[[:alpha:][:digit:]]", test_cases)] <- ""
```

See the [R demo](https://tio.run/##TY6xCoAwDER3vyJmEAs6uBb/pAQJtlTBQWz/P9pG0CXvjlyOXCI5pLysnEKCeYS1R8YBsKujgwpQp0bXUDGpVryGwRfBgKb5ul0br3AePTpn@Tg3tuSs3@OeLdGT/5KGyh@Iv@NG5AY)

The `!grepl("[[:alpha:][:digit:]]", test_cases)` command will only fetch the items that do not contain any letter (`[:alpha:]`) or digit (`[:digit:]`).

Output

```
 [1] "a"     ""      ""      ""      ""      "&a"    "& a"   "1"     "& 1"  
[10] "&1"    "& a d" "a "
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. I tend to over complicate my egexes all the time and I am always unsure whether I should remove unwanted parts or keep wanted parts in `gsubs`. Your answer boils down to the essential. thanks.